# Is there any way to make RecycleViewer items clickable in order to open new activity?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have make on click listener to my recycle view adapter in order to open new activity or the on activity with the same structure and fetch different information using firebase for every single one. The on click listener its working but with the current code i can only make every item open the same activity. I need find a solution to take the position or something for every item and show different content.

```
- My Adapter for the recycleview




     public class MyRestaurantsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRestaurantsAdapter.MyRestaurantsViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<RestaurantsModel> RestaurantsModelList;
    private  ItemClickListener mItemListener;




    public MyRestaurantsAdapter(Context context, List<RestaurantsModel> restaurantsModelList,ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.RestaurantsModelList = restaurantsModelList;
        this.mItemListener = itemClickListener;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyRestaurantsAdapter.MyRestaurantsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyRestaurantsAdapter.MyRestaurantsViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.restaurant_item,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyRestaurantsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(RestaurantsModelList.get(position).getImage())
                .into(holder.imageView);
        holder.txtName.setText(new StringBuilder().append(RestaurantsModelList.get(position).getName()));
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            mItemListener.onItemClick(RestaurantsModelList.get(position));
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return RestaurantsModelList.size();
    }
    public interface  ItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(RestaurantsModel restaurantsModelList);


    }

    public class MyRestaurantsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.imageView)
        ImageView imageView;
        @BindView(R.id.txtName)
        TextView txtName;


        private Unbinder unbinder;


        public MyRestaurantsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);

        }
    }
}
    
 - My Class

    public class PizzaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IRestaurantsLoadListener, ICartLoadListener {
    @BindView(R.id.recycler_restaurants)
    RecyclerView recyclerRestaurants;
    @BindView(R.id.mainLayout)
    RelativeLayout mainLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.badge)
    NotificationBadge badge;
    @BindView(R.id.btnCart)
    FrameLayout btnCart;

    IRestaurantsLoadListener restaurantsLoadListener;
    ICartLoadListener cartLoadListener;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pizza);
        init();
        loadRestaurantsFromFirebase();
    }

    private void loadRestaurantsFromFirebase() {
        List<RestaurantsModel> restaurantsModels = new ArrayList<>();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("Restaurants").child("Pizza")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            for (DataSnapshot restaurantsSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()){
                                RestaurantsModel restaurantsModel = restaurantsSnapshot.getValue(RestaurantsModel.class);
                                restaurantsModel.setKey(restaurantsSnapshot.getKey());
                                restaurantsModels.add(restaurantsModel);
                            }
                            restaurantsLoadListener.onRestaurantsLoadSuccess(restaurantsModels);
                        }
                        else {
                            restaurantsLoadListener.onRestaurantsLoadFailed("Cant find Pizza Restaurants");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        restaurantsLoadListener.onRestaurantsLoadFailed(error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }


    private void init() {
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        restaurantsLoadListener = this;
        cartLoadListener = this;

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
        recyclerRestaurants.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recyclerRestaurants.addItemDecoration(new SpaceItemDecoration());

    }


    @Override
    public  void  onRestaurantsLoadSuccess(List<RestaurantsModel>restaurantsModelList){
        MyRestaurantsAdapter adapter = new MyRestaurantsAdapter(this, restaurantsModelList, new MyRestaurantsAdapter.ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(RestaurantsModel restaurantsModel ){

                showCatalog();
            }
        });
        recyclerRestaurants.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void showCatalog() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PizzaCatalogActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestaurantsLoadFailed(String message) {
        Snackbar.make(mainLayout,message,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCartLoadSuccess(List<CartModel> cartModelList) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCartLoadFailed(String message) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? However, I think this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseApp-Clean-Architecture-MVVM) might help.

Comment: Hello i update my code and my description to be more clear. Generally what i what to do its to make on click listener in a recycle viewer in order to show different content for every item

Comment: Ok, and what isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: All the items open the same activity.

Comment: In that case, instead of using only the PizzaCatalogActivity, choose the activity you want, right?

Comment: Yes exactly. Base on the position of the recycleviewer and other activity

Comment: Try to use a switch statement, with cases for each activity. Most likely it will help you solve the problem.